# Why is my static class identifier not the same for two different compilation targets in C++?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, rtti

I use a base `Message` class used to communicate between two plugins (different compilation targets) in C++. The `Message` class is meant to be inherited. Then, each plugin can downcast the received `Message` based on an unique identifier.

```cpp
class Message
{
public:
    Message(int id) : m_id(id) {}

    int id() const noexcept {
        return m_id;
    }

protected:
    int m_id;
};

template <class T>
class IdentifiedMessage : public Message
{
public:
    static const int id;
    explicit IdentifiedMessage() noexcept : Message(id) {}
};

inline int createId() noexcept
{
    static int id = 0;
    return id++;
}

template <class T>
const int IdentifiedMessage<T>::id = createId();
```

Inherited classes are implemented like that using CRTP for automatic `id` creation:

```cpp
class ConcreteMessage final : public IdentifiedMessage<ConcreteMessage>
{
public:
    ConcreteMessage()
    : IdentifiedMessage<ConcreteMessage>()
    {}
};
```

And then it's used like that:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Message> message = std::make_unique<ConcreteMessage>();
    std::cout << "Id matches: " << static_cast<bool>(message->id() == ConcreteMessage::id) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

The problem I'm facing: I observed that **`ConcreteMessage::id` was different between two plugins**.

This prevented the application from working properly. I don't know where it could be coming from. I guess it's related to a compile order, dependency, or cache problem (the application is split in multiple targets, for example `libMessage.so`, `libSpecificMessage.so`, `libPluginA.so`, `libPluginB.so`, etc.). The issue happens very rarely, and I guess a clean build would get rid of it.

It seems very complicated to identify what could have goes wrong in the compilation process. So, I'm wondering if there is a fundamental problem in the way ids are generated? Does using `std::type_index` would prevent this kind of issue to happen again?

Comment: One example that comes to mind is a case of two platforms with different endianness. This is because 'communicate' --> 'serialize' --> 'subjected to platform endianness'.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Thanks for the idea. The application is compiled and run on the same platform, though.

Comment: Your issue sounds similar to static initialization order fiasco, you can't rely in which order static objects in different translation units are initialized in, as even small changes like the order of compiling .cpp files can change that. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof

Comment: Sharing of static data across shared libraries/DLLs is tricky. Why not just use a dynamic cast?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Unfortunately, this is how it is implemented in the codebase where I work. Using `dynamic_cast` seems more appropriate indeed, thanks (but it requires a big refactoring). In the short term, do you think that using `type_index` could avoid SIOF (still using `static`, but at least without being dependent on the order)? It worked when I tested it, but that's just maybe due to the recompilation.

Comment: I don't know how well type_index works across shared libraries. You should test it and perhaps look at the generated assembly.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I was wondering how `dynamic_cast` could correctly identify the same type across shared libraries if `typeid()` / `type_index` can't, but indeed there is no guarantee it's implemented in the same way. I'll try investigating that further, thanks.